# RIA with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, service, ria

Does it make sense to use RIA Services as a service provider to an ASP.NET web application as opposed to just a Silverlight application? We have an infrastructure constraint that the services and the consumer are on different physical machines thus need to cross a service boundary. We have not seen any examples of using ASP.NET as a consumer of RIA Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can here is a post that walks through using WCF RIA Services in a regular ASP.net Web Application.

[http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/12/14/using-wcf-ria-services-without-silverlight-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123025826/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/12/14/using-wcf-ria-services-without-silverlight-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Comment: The post linked in the answer shows using the WCF RIA Services which are built within the application. But you should be able to use a WCF RIA Services project to create a separate project and consume the web DLL just like you would consume the Silverlight DLL in a Silverlight project.